# template linking error

Tags: c++, g++, c++11

I have an header, where I put the *definition* of a function template:

```
template <typename FT, typename std::enable_if< !std::is_array<FT>::value, int >::type =0 >
int fieldRW(lua_State* l, FT* ptr, bool write){ return scalarFieldRW<FT>(l, ptr, write); }
```

in a .cpp unit I get a pointer to this template function, and I expect the compiler to instantiate the template:

```
typedef int (*_fieldRW)(lua_State*, void*, bool);
int dummy=3;
_fieldRW aFunctionPointer=_fieldRW(fieldRW<decltype(dummy)>);
```

Everything compiles. But I get the following link-time error:

> /home/pisto/sorgenti/hopmodv4/src/fpsgame/server.cpp:39: undefined
>   reference to `int fieldRW(lua_State*, int*, bool)'

Notice that the compiler correctly picks the template defined in the header (because it adds the default second argument of the template), but apparently it fails to actually instantiate the template.

EDIT:
this looks definitely like a bug. See these tests: http://pastebin.com/5Yjsv47H
Also, another clue that this is likely to be a bug in g++ is that if I do this:

```
int main() {
        int dummy=3;
        int (*inted)(int*)=asd<decltype(dummy)>;
        int (*voided)(void*)=(int (*)(void*))asd<decltype(dummy)>;
        voided(&dummy);
}
```

g++ warns about the unused variable `inted` but compiles finely.

Comment: is type param `FT*` supposed to be `void *` or `int *`?  Your code and linker error seem to disagree.

Comment: I expect the last line of the second code snippet to instantiate a fieldRW function with FT=int. Doesn't matter if then I cast the function to another function type, it's only for the completeness of my example.

Comment: Ah ok, casting to a different function pointer type (which feels like a deeply peculiar thing to do anyway) threw me. I don't have the standard handy to check function template instantiation rules, hoepfully someone else does ...

Comment: I have to mix template-aware and non-aware code, that's the point of the pointer cast

Comment: That doesn't really explain why you changed the second argument from `int*` to `void*`.  Does it work if you explicitly instantiate the function template?

Comment: this is weird. I tried to actually call the function template, and it compiles correctly. Should I conclude that getting the pointer of a template function is "too weak" to make the compiler instantiate it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6897/discussion-between-useless-and-lorenzo-pistone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is probably a subtleness in the specs of function pointer casting:

> The standard says in [expr.reinterpret.cast]
>   "A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a
>   different type. The effect of calling a function through a pointer to a
>   function type (8.3.5) that is not the same as the type used in the definition
>   of the function is undefined."
>
> So I think the program has undefined behaviour.  Because you never call
>   asd as part of a valid expression it doesn't need to be instantiated.
>
> Clang++ fails in the same way as G++ 4.6, but it works with G++ 4.7

(Thanks to Jonathan Wakely)

Comment: Casting function pointers is really bad.  Code should never cast function pointers, except those returned from `dlsym` or `GetProcAddress`, and even then only to their true type.

Comment: I will cast them back to the real signature right before using. I have to do so because I store the pointer in a list which contain heterogeneous types of function pointers (namely, all differing in the type of pointers of the second argument).

Comment: You don't need to use illegal casts to do that.  Instead, put the function pointers in a structure with a common base class.